# Securing my data when recycling iPod at the Apple Store

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-store

I'd like to get a new iPod touch, I'd also like to not have to re-input all my contacts and notes (don't mind clearing out the apps) but I want to make sure of two things before I go in and take advantage of the 10% discount at the Apple Store.

1. Can I backup my data on an as updated as possible 2nd gen iPod and restore it onto a shiny new 4th gen iPod?
2. Can I make sure (within reason) that my data is cleared off the iPod when I turn it in to the Apple store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes, your backed up data in iTunes from your 2nd gen iPod should be able to be restored into a new 4th gen iPod, based on my experience upgrading from a 1st gen iPod Touch to an iPhone.
- Regarding clearing data, check out this ZDnet [blog post](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/hardware/how-to-wipe-your-old-ipadiphoneipod-touch-ready-for-resale/11839). It includes information about the `Erase all Content and Settings` option that you can use to wipe the iPod, including a quote from Apple Support. More specific details for all Apple iDevices can be found on this [Apple page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2110).